# Disable contextmenu but NOT in textboxes

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, dom-events, contextmenu

I want to disable the contextmenu on my page, because I have an own. But in the textboxes it should be possible to use the system contextmenu.

I'm doing it with Javascript like that:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    return false;
};
```

I thought about something like:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    if (e.taget.nodeName != "text") {
    return false;
    }
};
```

But the nodeName is every time a DIV.
In this DIV I have an JQGrid where are the textboxes in.

```
<div id="divGrdPos" style="padding:3px,0px,3px,0px;">
    <table id="JQGridCart" class="grdCart"></table>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT' && event.target.type !== 'text' && event.target.nodeName !== 'TEXTAREA') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It will work for inputs (type="text") and textareas.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QjmHy/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking against `text` textbox `nodeName` is `INPUT`

```
document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT") {
        return false;
    }
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qr3fu/

Comment: Also if I write input it doesn't work because i get a DIV. The Input field is in this DIV with many other controls from the JQGrid. so I can't check if I click on this Input field...

Comment: @Senni The input field in my fiddle is also in a div, maybe you could set up a live demo so we can investigate it?

Comment: sorry but this is not possible because I can't load the JQGrid there. It's an input field inside this JQGrid...

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
In my code I have a `mousedown()` event on my grid and this event fires before the `oncontextmenu()` event. and my `mousedown()` is greating my own contextmenu with a div
after checking the right click.

So I checked in my `mousedown()` event if the `nodeName` is `"input"` and handle the result.

the `oncontextmenu()` will be the same.

thx for your tips.